# Custom Select Query for meta table

Tags: mysql, sql, search, select, metadata

I have a table structure as shown below

[image]

I am running a query for search that searches for property id with provided 
meta_value against meta_name.

I have used union, self join, union all methods but were not working, please suggest me query that will get a data

mysql queries are

1)

```
SELECT property_id from
real_new_properties
where (meta_name = 'price' and meta_value = '1000')
  and (meta_name = 'propertyvalue' and meta_value = '10000')
```

2)

```
SELECT property_id
from real_new_properties
where meta_name = 'price'
  and meta_value = '1000'
UNION
SELECT property_id
from real_new_properties
where meta_name = 'propertyvalue'
  and meta_value = '10000'
```

3)

```
SELECT property_id
from real_new_properties
where meta_name = 'price'
  and meta_value = '1000'
UNION ALL
SELECT property_id
from real_new_properties
where meta_name = 'propertyvalue'
  and meta_value = '10000'
```

Comment: you should try putting all of what you mentioned in a `select` query

Comment: Do you mean both meta_name = 'price'... AND meta_name = 'propertyvalue'... should be fulfilled, or just one of them? Show us the expected result (with the above data.)

Comment: @jarlh - II mean both the cases must be fulfilled.

Comment: Then you could use a GROUP BY, or a self-join.

Comment: I have tried self join but not working, and group by will not work with my case.

Comment: I'm absolutely sure both suggested solutions are doable.

Comment: can you please share query? as I am unable to create one as you were saying

Comment: @jarlh - here is self join query but not working "SELECT a.property_id FROM real_new_properties a, real_new_properties b WHERE a.property_id = b.property_id and (a.meta_name = 'price' and a.meta_value = '1000') and (a.meta_name = 'propertyvalue' and a.meta_value = '10000')   "

Comment: Do you want all 3 rows with property_id = 1? (Or just the two of them?)

Answer (score 0):

to get all that have `meta_name` `price` and `propertyvalue` and `meta_value` `1000` and `10000` respectively, you need to do this.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE (meta_name = 'price' and meta_value = '1000') OR (meta_name = 'propertyvalue' and meta_value = '10000')
```

this will select both from `table` where `meta_name = 'price' and meta_value = '1000'` and `meta_name = 'propertyvalue' and meta_value = '10000'`

Comment: I need both conditions to be satisfied, but If put this query then it is giving me blank data instead it should give me result SELECT * FROM `real_new_properties` WHERE (meta_name = 'price' and meta_value = '1000') AND (meta_name = 'propertyvalue' and meta_value = '10000') ORDER BY `meta_value` ASC

Comment: yes, you'll get an empty result set as you don't have data in the table to satisfy both conditions. Try to run the above query please and let me know you can find something or not?

Comment: it is working in "or" case but I need both conditions to be true using "and" case and even providing correct content in "and" query the output is not coming here is my query "SELECT * FROM real_new_properties WHERE (meta_name = 'price' and meta_value = '1000') AND (meta_name = 'propertyvalue' and meta_value = '10000')"

Comment: what output you're expecting?