# How can I get data from a table that fulfill two or more conditions on meta data table?

Tags: mysql

I know this is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32718318/custom-select-query-for-meta-table) but there is still no working answer yet and I will try to explain better.

So I have THREE tables, which are `member`, `meta_name`, and `meta_value`. I think you already know how they are related to each other. For example, assume I have these rows:

`member` table:

```
memberID | name
   1     | john
```

`meta_name` table:

```
meta_nameID | name
     1      | address
     2      | jobTitle
```

`meta_value` table:

```
meta_valueID | meta_nameID | memberID | value
     1       |      1      |    1     | California
     2       |      2      |    1     | Manager
```

So John has two meta data which are address and jobTitle. The meta data are stored in `meta_value` table, and the `mete_value` table has identifiers in `meta_name` table. It's just a basic meta data system.

Now the question is, **how can I get members that fulfill two or more conditions on the `meta_value` table**? Something like, "get members that have an address at California AND a jobTitle as Manager"?

I have tried this query:

```
SELECT * FROM member JOIN meta_value ON member.memberID = meta_value.memberID WHERE (meta_nameID = '1' AND value = '3') AND (meta_nameID = '2' AND value = 'Jonggol')
```

I know that's an ugly-not working query but I hope that will help you understand what I'm going to achieve. Thanks!

NOTE: I actually don't need the `meta_value` table data. I just want to get members that fulfill the conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of different options.
Straightforward:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    member
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            meta_value
        WHERE
                meta_value.memberID = member.memberID
            AND meta_value.meta_nameID = 1
            AND meta_value.value = '3'
    )
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            meta_value
        WHERE
                meta_value.memberID = member.memberID
            AND meta_value.meta_nameID = 2
            AND meta_value.value = 'Jonggol'
    )
```

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    member
WHERE
    memberID IN (
        SELECT
            memberID
        FROM
            meta_value
        WHERE
                meta_value.meta_nameID = 1
            AND meta_value.value = '3'
    )
    AND memberID IN (
        SELECT
            memberID
        FROM
            meta_value
        WHERE
                meta_value.meta_nameID = 2
            AND meta_value.value = 'Jonggol'
    )
```

Another way:

```
SELECT
      member.*
    , SUM(IF((meta_value.meta_nameID = 1 AND meta_value.value = '3') OR (meta_value.meta_nameID = 2 AND meta_value.value = 'Jonggol'), 1, 0)) AS x
FROM
    member
    INNER JOIN meta_value ON (
        meta_value.memberID = member.memberID
    )
GROUP BY
    member.memberID
HAVING
    x = 2
```

However, I'd like to note that such DB schema should only be used to store data that require filtering.

Comment: The first option gives me some errors. But I tried the second option and it works. Thanks!

Comment: That strange. I copy/pasted it in my client and 1 and 2 queries works. Changed '3' by 'California' & 'Jonggol' by 'Manager' and it found 'john'. In the last query it was error (I keyed in 'meta_nameID.value' instead of 'meta_value.value'). Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

**You need to use sub queries. Try the following query to select members with a particular address and a job title.**

```
SELECT member.name
FROM member
WHERE 
    memberID IN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT memberID 
        FROM meta_value
        WHERE meta_nameID IN
                (SELECT DISTINCT meta_nameID FROM meta_name WHERE name='address') 
                AND value='California')
    AND memberID IN
        (SELECT DISTINCT memberID 
        FROM meta_value
        WHERE meta_nameID IN 
                (SELECT DISTINCT meta_nameID FROM meta_name WHERE name='jobTitle') 
                AND value='Manager')
```

**You also try a smaller query using with clause:**

(Here we are creating a tmp table which has both address and job title, later join the address separately to get just address and jobTitle to get just job title. This will give you a member level table with address and jobTitle as columns for easy use in any subsequent queries)

```
WITH tmp AS
(SELECT * FROM meta_value mv INNER JOIN meta_name mn ON mv.meta_nameID=mn.meta_nameID)
SELECT member.name , add.value , job.value
FROM member 
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM tmp WHERE name='address') add ON member.memberID = add.memberID
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM tmp WHERE name='jobTitle') job ON member.memberID = job.memberID
WHERE add.value  = 'required address' AND add.job.value ='required job title'
```

Comment: This also works! I think I will learn more about sub queries. I got the topic to learn. Thanks!